# Vault, How to force tokens to be created under an specific policy?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I would like to allow token that belongs to a policy to be able to create another tokens, but I will only allow those new tokens to be generated assigned to an specific policy (of course this policy must be also applied to 'parent' token).

Tried using policies directive 'allowed_parameters' and setting policies to allow only desired policy but it does not seems to work or I used wrong format... Has anyone made this work? Is it possible to use allowed_paramaters over policies parameter?

Use case explanation: Provide to users/applications can only create token under that closed policy so they can provide to anyone else. I have the option to use Approle Auth here but I would like to manage the parent tokens on my own by using token auth.

Comment: can you post some code of what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `-policy` to force use policy to any token.
For instance,

Create a policy,

```
  path "secret/*"
  {
    capabilities = ["create", "read", "list"]
  }
```

and write it to vault,

```
./vault policy write issue_cert po.hcl
```

Now create a token which uses this policy,

```
./vault token create -policy="issue_cert"
```

Now check if policy is applied to new token,

```
curl -X GET \
  http://192.168.17.154:8200/v1//auth/token/lookup-self \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-vault-token: 6abdfde0-caf5-2687-df62-07d2e30bf21a' \
  -d '{
  "token": "e3cffb2b-9b7b-5dcc-baf3-bd67cf16affc"
}'
```

will give you,

```
{
    "request_id": "bd351c1c-2185-3471-9abe-aaf5ed0dadd7",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 0,
    "data": {
        "accessor": "41f14bc3-110c-00b8-1b6e-faaa3b455a15",
        "creation_time": 1536888189,
        "creation_ttl": 2764800,
        "display_name": "token",
        "entity_id": "",
        "expire_time": "2018-10-16T12:23:09.139654113+11:00",
        "explicit_max_ttl": 0,
        "id": "6abdfde0-caf5-2687-df62-07d2e30bf21a",
        "issue_time": "2018-09-14T11:23:09.139653867+10:00",
        "meta": null,
        "num_uses": 0,
        "orphan": false,
        "path": "auth/token/create",
        "policies": [
            "default",
            "issue_cert"
        ],
        "renewable": true,
        "ttl": 2764596
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

Regarding,

> (of course this policy must be also applied to 'parent' token)

This isn't always the case. For instance, if you are using a root as a parent token, its not necessary that root is using the policy you need to apply.